# Notification number does not display on all phones

Tags: android, notifications

I'm having issues with using the number property of the notificationmanager.  It works on the emulator and other phone I've used.  However, it does not seem to display on my Droid Incredible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem. It appears to be a bug in the HTC Incredible, and the EVO 4G as well. I will attempt to take this up with HTC...somehow.